# Should device enter to doze mode with device admin app?

Tags: android

Should device enter to doze mode with device admin app?

I tried search any info in documentation. But no info about this case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it will work for your case but have you tried this link? This is the first I answers the questions in StackOverflow, please comment if something is missing.

Here is the code:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

[developer.android.com]
[1]: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33982353)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will notice it a next time.

Comment: I mind should device go away to doze mode, while device admin app working in background(e.g service)&

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, may my answer is digressed. I think my experience is not enough to give the right answer. Hope you receive a response useful.